# CMake of google-cloud-cpp Fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cmake, google-cloud-cpp

The CMake build of [`google-cloud-cpp`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp) fails with this error:

```
$ cmake -H. -Bcmake-out
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at google/cloud/storage/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "google_cloud_cpp_common" with any of the following names:

    google_cloud_cpp_commonConfig.cmake
    google_cloud_cpp_common-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "google_cloud_cpp_common" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "google_cloud_cpp_common_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "google_cloud_cpp_common" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Is this the [repo](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp) you are trying to compile?

Comment: @squareskittles https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp yes

Comment: Ok, that repo has specific instructions for building on different environments (Mac, Linux, etc), did you follow those instructions? Specifically, `cmake -Hsuper -Bcmake-out`. Note, the *source* directory should be `super`, did you run your command from the `super` directory?

Comment: In the `INSTALL.md` file they mentioned something else: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-google-cloud-cpp

Comment: Yes, but the note in the `INSTALL.md` file says those commands **only** apply "*If all the dependencies of google-cloud-cpp are installed and provide CMake support files*". It appears you have *not* installed all of the dependencies. However, the same file has instructions for installing *specific* missing dependencies for each environment (Linux, Mac, etc.), so you probably need to *install* the missing `google_cloud_cpp_common`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works by `cmake -Hsuper -Bcmake-out`.

Comment: Glad it works! Added a response to more clearly explain things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CMake command:

```
cmake -H. -Bcmake-out
```

will *only* work well after you have installed **all** of the `google-cloud-cpp` dependencies. From the [`INSTALL.md`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md#installing-google-cloud-cpp) file:

> **If** all the dependencies of `google-cloud-cpp` are installed and provide CMake support files, then compiling and installing the libraries requires two commands:
>
> ```
> cmake -H. -Bcmake-out
> cmake --build cmake-out --target install
> ```
>
> Unfortunately getting your system to this state may require multiple steps, the following sections describe how to install `google-cloud-cpp` on several platforms.

It goes on to describe how to install each of the dependencies individually, for several platforms. This is a painful process, but an easier approach is use the suggested CMake super-build, described in the main [`README.md`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp#linux) file. This will download and build all of the `google-cloud-cpp` dependencies for you. Try the CMake super-build command instead:

```
cmake -Hsuper -Bcmake-out
```